# How to improve JDK 8 nashorn engine performance?

Tags: java, nashorn

We have a requirement where we need to execute several short JavaScript snippets via Java. For that we are using the Nashorn engine that comes embedded along with Java. Java version is 1.8.0_191.

We initialize the script engine only once in the life cycle of the program. Then we pre-compile the snippets (as the snippets will repeat) in cache. We use pre-compiled scripts for eval. The bindings will be different each time and those are created before every execution.

Following is the snippet.

```
public class RuleExecutor {

    private ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn"); 
    private Map<String, CompiledScript> ruleCache = new HashMap<>();
    ..
    ....

    public Object execute(Rule rule) {
        Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings(); 
        bindings.put(....);
        compiled = ruleCache.get(rule.getTarget());
        if (compiled == null) {
            compiled = ((Compilable) engine).compile(rule.getExpr());
            ruleCache.put(rule.getTarget(), compiled);
        }
        compiled.eval(bindings);
        output = bindings.get(rule.getTarget());
        return output;
     }
```

The rule expressions can be arbitrary self contained scripts. However they repeat, hence the caching.
With the above, we are getting 120000 executions per minute. 
How do we expedite the executions ?

Comment: One can use java objects and methods. Probably some analysis is required. Bulk processing in JavaScript can be costly because of the variable implementation: a value can be anything, and because of the scripting engine overhead (lookups).

Answer (score 2):

Performance improved greatly on creating the Bindings only once during the program life cycle. After each execution, the bindings need to be cleared using **bindings.clear()**